# CodeIgniter form_validation not working properly

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am new to php. My setup is lamp on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
I have created a Login system with the help of online tutorials.
I have already made changes in `autoload.php` file as

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');
```

Unexpectedly, when both the username and password fields are left empty, and Login button is pressed, **no** errors (that 'Username field is empty'...)are displayed.
Moreover, in Mozilla Firefox the page remains the same on pressing the button
and in Google Chrome, the page loads to about:blank .

Please help and sorry if i made a mistake in the question format.

**My controller: LoginController.php**

```
<?php

class LoginController extends CI_Controller{

public function index(){

    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function checkLogin(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username' , 'Username' , 'required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' , 'Password' , 'required|callback_verifyUser');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $this->load->view('login');

    }else{
        redirect('HomeController/index');
    }

}
public function verifyUser(){
    $name = $this->input->post('username');
    $pass = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->model('LoginModel');

    if($this->LoginModel->login($name, $pass)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('verifyUser', 'Incorrect email or password. Please try again.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

**My view file: login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CI Login System</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
        <?php echo form_open('LoginController/checkLogin'); ?>
        Username<br/>
        <input type="text", name="username"/><br/>
        Password<br/>
        <input type="text", name="passsword"/><br/>
        <input type="submit", value="Login", name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your error here?

Comment: I have edited the question. There is no error. However, the errors that 'particular fields are empty' as they were shown in the tutorials i am watching, do not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the HTML code.

```
Username<br/>
<input type="text", name="username"/><br/>
Password<br/>
<input type="text", name="passsword"/><br/>
<input type="submit", value="Login", name="submit"/>
```

This is what is wrong:

1. You don't put commas in a HTML tag.
2. Password input should be of type password.
3. Your input name for password is wrong, it has an extra `s` where there shouldn't be, considering this line:

   `$pass = $this->input->post('password');`

Test this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder = "Username" name="username" required/><br>
<input type="password" placeholder = "Password" name="password" required/><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
```

I have edited my answer to insert the `required` attribute.

But the compatibility is not as huge as it should be:

[image]

You can also use a [Javascript form validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) approach

Comment: Thanks for your time! I have applied the changes but the "empty field" errors are still not generated!

Comment: So we must apply a required attribute, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You rock man, that just worked!!

Answer (score 1):

No it will never work. You are c**onflicting Normal `<form>` and Codeigniter form Code**

form code should be

```
echo form_open('LoginController/checkLogin');

$userName = array(
  'name'        => 'username',
  'id'          => 'username'
);
$password = array(
  'name'        => 'password',
  'id'          => 'password'
);


echo "<label>Username</label>";
echo form_input($userName);

echo "<label>Password</label>"; 
echo form_password($password);

echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Login');
echo form_close();
```

1. [How to Create a Contact Form In CodeIgniter](http://www.formget.com/create-a-form-in-codeigniter/)
2. [CodeIgniter Form Validation](http://www.formget.com/form-validation-using-codeigniter/)

Comment: Thanks but still no "empty field" errors generated.

Comment: @MohitGarg check  second link.